# DHTMLx: Send error message from server in response to form.save()

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

Question about Js UI framework DHTMLx. I have try many ways but unable to send error text in response to form.save(). Tryd different methods, events on client side, but unable to send any message.

One of the variants I try:
On server side:

```
$form = new FormConnector($conn);
function beforeProcessing($action) {
  $action->set_response_attribute(‘msg’,‘Server’);
  $action->set_response_text(“error”);
  $action->invalid();
}
$form->event->attach(“beforeProcessing”,“beforeProcessing”);
```

On client side:

```
myForm.attachEvent("onAfterSave", function (id, xml){
  log.msg(xml);
  log.msg(xml.msg);
});
myForm.attachEvent("onAfterUpdate", function (id,action,tid,response){
  log.msg(response);
});
```

No one variant prints message from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out how to pass text, and also make it json. This counld be easy operation but I have a deal with DHTMLx javascript framework with php connectors(from same company), it have documentation but not everything covered with docs. The key of solution is `xml.textContent` and its not documented.

On server side:

```
$form = new FormConnector($conn);
function beforeProcessing($action) {
  var $data['error'] = 'text message'
  $action->set_response_text(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
  $action->invalid(); // mark request as invalid so insert/update not called
}
$form->event->attach(“beforeProcessing”,“beforeProcessing”);
```

On client side:

```
myForm.attachEvent("onAfterSave", function (id, xml){
  var r = JSON.parse(xml.textContent);
  if (r.error) log.error(r.error);
  //other json processing if needed
}); // log.error from other library, replace it
```

I wish we have more DHTMLx developers here, and help together.